# Javascript Regular Expression Replace

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace all occurrences of of a pattern in JavaScript.

My string could look like this:

;2;#French/1;12;#German/7

the pattern is I'm trying to replace is:

a ; followed by a number followed by a ; followed by a #

I want to replace all occurrences with a comma followed by a blank space: ', '

So, the above example would result in

, French/1, German/7

Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difficulty to do that with regex

Match pattern = `;\d+;#`

Replace pattern = `,`